# How can I create a function to check if a user is blocked?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app is being prepared for apple app store distribution and the last thing that I need to do is allow users to block another user. My idea was that in a user on firebase, there would be a collection called blocked and it would have documents with the name of blocked users, then whenever a user opens a profile, the app checks if the user of that profile is blocked, and if they are blocked, it just shows a title saying that the user is blocked, instead of showing the regular profile info.

Here is what the code that adds the blocked user to the list looks like:

```
public func BlockUser(username: String) {
    let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username") as! String
    let ref = database.collection("users")
        .document(currentUser)
        .collection("blocked")
        .document(username)
    ref.setData(["username": username])
}
```

And that works because this is what shows up in firestore:

[image]

So then to do the second part (checking if a profile user is in the blocked list) I use this code:

```
public var userIsBlocked: Bool = false

public func IsBlockedByUser(username: String) {
    let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username") as! String
    let ref = database.collection("users")
        .document(currentUser)
        .collection("blocked")
        .document(username)
    ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            self.userIsBlocked = true
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
            self.userIsBlocked = false
        }
    }
}
```

However, even if a user is on the blocked list when I open their profile, it still prints "Document does not exist.". I used googles sample code to look for the document so why is it not finding it?

Comment: My Firebase Auth only uses email and password. The username and is stored in Firestore with all the users posts and stuff. I don't see why User Defaults is a bad place to store the username. Could you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing username with user ID. But I'm not so sure I'd store username in User Defaults anyway because I don't think it's the appropriate place. I'd consider creating an object that manages the user that stores the user's information, like username, and listens for changes in Auth state. When the app launches, the object is populated if the user is signed in and carries that information until the user signs out. There isn't any need to persist this data beyond the app's lifecycle, is there?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't see an issue with the code I had previously used but I replaced it with a query and this seems to have fixed the issue. Here's the new code I'm using to search for if a user is blocked:

```
public var userIsBlocked: Bool = false

public func UserIsBlocked(username: String) {
    let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username") as! String
    let ref = database.collection("users")
        .document(currentUser)
        .collection("blocked")
    ref.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            self.userIsBlocked = false
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                self.userIsBlocked = true
            }
        }
    }
}


public var blockedByUser: Bool = false

public func IsBlockedByUser(username: String) {
    let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username") as! String
    let ref = database.collection("users")
        .document(currentUser)
        .collection("blockedBy")
    ref.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            self.blockedByUser = false
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                self.blockedByUser = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then when a user's profile is opened, these functions are called to check if the current user has either blocked the user whose profile they are trying to view or have been blocked by them. Based on the result, the two variables are set to either true or false. If they are both false, the profile loads, and if either of them is true, the profile does not load and shows an alert before returning to the previous view controller. This code is all over the place but it gets the job done!